# Strange scala macro behaviour when checking for abstract type?

Tags: scala, types, macros, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to code a simple **type builder** in scala. Anyway, the type builder it self works like a charm.
I want to check in the typebuilder for an **abstract** class.

At **runtime** there is no problem for that:

```
if (classSymbol.isAbstract) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provided class is abstract")
```

I tag the method with a **TypeTag** attribute, so scala do not erasure the time during compiling.

```
def createInstance[T: TypeTag]: T
```

Anyway this is working. I don't prefer this way, cause the user can enter an **abstract class** and want to create it. I don't want to check for argument exception at runtime.

So I thought it would really cool to check for the right type during **compile time**.
This is the complete code of the **macro** function:

```
object ClassCheckMacro {

  def checkClass[T](x: T): T = macro checkClassImpl[T]

  def checkClassImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(x: c.Tree) = {
    import c.universe._
    val symbol = weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol
    if (symbol.isAbstract) {
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"${symbol.fullName} must be a class")
    } else {
        c.Expr(q"($x)")
    }
  }
}
```

Evertime I use this macro, I get the abort message *"must be a class"*.
It doesn't matter if it is a class or an abstract type.
Usage:

```
    val typeInfo = typeOf[T]
    val classSymbol = typeInfo.typeSymbol.asClass
    ClassCheckMacro.checkClass(classSymbol)
```

Are there any hints for this "strange" behaviour?

Comment: Did you intend `checkClass(new C)`?

Comment: Yep, some kind of it. for 'new C' I have to put the typeSymbol, cause you can not create a new instance of a generic type ;)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how to invoke it. Given `class C`, try `checkClass[C](null)`, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is just a value.

```
$ scalam -language:_
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import reflect.macros._
import reflect.macros._

scala>   def checkClassImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(x: c.Tree) = {
     |     import c.universe._
     |     val symbol = weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol
     |     if (symbol.isAbstract) {
     |         c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"${symbol.fullName} must be a class")
     |     } else {
     |         c.Expr(q"($x)")
     |     }
     |   }
checkClassImpl: [T](c: scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context)(x: c.Tree)(implicit evidence$1: c.WeakTypeTag[T])c.Expr[T]

scala> def checkClass[T](x: T): T = macro checkClassImpl[T]
defined term macro checkClass: [T](x: T)T

scala> class C
defined class C

scala> checkClass[C](null)
res0: C = null

scala> abstract class K
defined class K

scala> checkClass[K](null)
<console>:17: error: K must be a class
       checkClass[K](null)
                    ^
```

In the middle of upgrading the work laptop to Windows 10...

Comment: Yep, the parameter is quiet useless. I tried it without parameter before, then I thought the macro implementation needs this to retrieve the right class. I updated the project to scala "2.12.0-M5" but same problem again. Anyway thank you very much for your answer... :)